# What trick will give most reliable/compatible sound alarm in a browser window for most browsers

Tags: jquery, audio, cross-browser, mp3, wav

I want to be able to play an alarm sound using Javascript in a browser window, preferably with the requirement for any browser plugins (Quicktime/Flash). I have been experimenting with the  tag and the new Audio object in Javascript, but results are mixed:

[image: Browser Test]

As you can see, there is no variant that works on all browsers.

Do I miss a trick that is more cross-browser compatible?

This is my code:

```
// mp3 with Audio object
var snd = new Audio("/sounds/beep.mp3");snd.play();

// wav with Audio object
var snd = new Audio("/sounds/beep.wav");snd.play();

// mp3 with EMBED tag
$("#alarmsound").empty().append
('<embed src="/sounds/beep.mp3" autostart="true" loop="false" '+
 'volume="100" hidden="true" width="1" height="1" />');

// wav with EMBED tag
$("#alarmsound").empty().append
('<embed src="/sounds/beep.wav" autostart="true" loop="false" '+
 'volume="100" hidden="true" width="1" height="1" />');
```

}

Comment: Also, <a href="sound.wav">Play</a> works in any version of Opera.

Comment: "<a href="sound.wav">Play</a>" is not what I am looking for, I need to initiate the sound from Javascript

Comment: I was doing some reading on character encoding, perhaps there's a hack out there to prompt a system beep, just an idea..

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried [HTML5's sound tag](http://www.w3schools.com/html5/tag_audio.asp)?

Answer (score 1):

Thank you for the table. I have the same problem. I don't want to use any flash, but it has to work on any platform. HTML 5 is only supported by newer Browsers and can't be used as a 'world wide' solution. There are still too many People using IE 6 :-) 
I used jQuery's browser property to manage the different objects:

```
if ($.browser.mozilla || $.browser.opera) {
  var snd = new Audio("beep.wav"); snd.play();
...
if ($.browser.msie) {
  var soundPlayer = $("<embed src='scripts/beep.mp3' hidden='true' autostart='true' loop='false' />");
  $("body").append(soundPlayer);
...
```