# Wait until sound finishes to use a web page

Tags: javascript, jquery, audio

I need to play a sound using JavaScript / jQuery. Currently, I'm using this code to play the sound:

```
var snd = new Audio('dir/file.wav');
snd.play();
```

What I need is a web page to be unusable until the sounds ends playing. Probably with some kind of dialog while the sound is playing. When the sound ends, the modal displays a "Ok" button, and after pressing the button, you can continue using the page.

Comment: What do you mean by "unusable", and why do you want this to be the case?

Comment: I mean that the user cannot touch anything in the screen while the sound is playing (buttons, etc). I need this because the sound are some instructions that need to be listened before the user can use the site.

Comment: @Vito I have given a very **short/simple** solution. Check it out.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**NOTE : This is not crossbrowser (HTML5 compatible browsers only)!**

For cross browser compatibility , you'll might want to look at this link : 
[What trick will give most reliable/compatible sound alarm in a browser window for most browsers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3013973/what-trick-will-give-most-reliable-compatible-sound-alarm-in-a-browser-window-fo?rq=1)

---

I'm seriously not good at explaining things but I made a JsFiddle for you.

http://jsfiddle.net/tnnjB/8/

Or here is the code :

HTML :

```
<audio id="myaudio" onended="onAudioEnded();">
  <source src="http://www.dccl.org/Sounds/pchick-alarm.wav" type="audio/wav">
Your browser does not support the audio element.
</audio>

<input 
    type="button" 
    value="You cannot click me before the sound is over" 
    onclick="javascript:alert('congrats!')"
/>
```

JAVASCRIPT :

```
$(function(){
    var audio = document.getElementById("myaudio");
    $.blockUI({message : "Listen to the music!" });  
    audio.play();
});

function onAudioEnded(){ 
    $.unblockUI();
    alert("It's over!!");
};
```

Things I have used : jquery, jquery-ui, jquery BlockUI plugin, HTML5 audio tag, google.

*Also, this example will not work on IE as it seems like IE does not accept the audio source to be on a remote host, but it will work if the file is local on your server.*

Hope this will help you achieve your need,

Marc

Comment: This one seem to be cool, but the HTML freezes after the sound is played and you cant do anything. Is there something you need to correct to get this working?

Comment: I tested this on FF, which browser did you use to test this it?

Comment: Just tested it on Firefox, it worked perfectly (thank you very much), but its not working on Chrome and IE10. Any clue about what can be wrong?

Comment: I just updated my answer so now everything should work on chrome, FireFox , IE(see my note on the answer) and all HTML5 compatible browsers.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help, its working now. This is exactly what I needed.

Comment: Just to note that the `<audio>` element only works in HTML5 in the first place, so I don't think you need to say that it only works on HTML5 browsers.

Answer (score 5):

Here is a way to do it with promises. Makes playing multiple audio files very easy.

```js
// makes playing audio return a promise
function playAudio(audio){
  return new Promise(res=>{
    audio.play()
    audio.onended = res
  })
}

// how to call
async function test(){
  const audio = new Audio('<url>')
  await playAudio(audio)
  // code that will run after audio finishes...
}
```

Comment: Thanks! very useful while playing multiple songs

Answer (score 0):

I thought about the following approach: Init a timer & wait until sound has played to end.

```
Show dialog/dimmed overlay layer
setInterval()
    -> Compare snd->currentTime with snd.duration. If they are the same
        -> Clear interval
        -> Hide dialog/Show OK button
```

Or

```
Show dialog/dimmed overlay layer
setInterval()
    -> Is snd.ended ?
        -> Clear interval
        -> Hide dialog/Show OK button
```

Answer (score 0):

There is a very **simple/short** solution

Use the following code syntax-

```
Audio_object=document.getElementById('audio_tag_id');
if(Audio_object.currentTime==Audio_object.duration)
alert('completely played.');
```

`audio_tag_id` is the id of the `<audio>`-element.

Comment: Thanks for answering. Unfortunately, I tested but it didnt work.

Answer (score -1):

You do this in a fashion so that it waits. 
Don't forget the `;` at the end of the wait function.

```
function snd() {
    var snd = new audio('yourFile.mp3');
    snd.play();
    wait(4000); //waits 4 seconds.
}
```

Comment: "wait" doesn't exist and there is no simple way to implement one. Plus, what are you talking about with ";" ?! There is NO NEED for it in JS, at least in the year you wrote this (2020).